# Create a process to update child record when the parent is updated - Not working on the TrailHead

Tags: salesforce

I am newbie to the salesforce and working on

**Create a process to update child record when the parent is updated.**

You've been given a requirement to keep Contact addresses in sync with the Account they belong to. Use Process Builder to create a new process that updates all child Contact addresses when the address of the Account record is updated. This process:

- Can have any name.
- Must be activated.
- Must update Contact mailing address fields (Street, City, State, Post Code, Country) when the parent Account shipping address field values are updated.
- NOTE: You may have to deactivate the validation rule for the Contacts object (created from a previous challenge) in order to complete this challenge.

[image]

The steps I created:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check weather there are any existing validation rules on Account or Contact object. or check any existing tiggers on them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all Field are update in the following order: (Street, City, State, Post Code, Country)

Order seems to be necessary for trailhead to verify the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking Shipping Address for the Account object and updating the Billing Address for contact. That might be the issue

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.